# JQuery AJAX - Not sending with data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a chatroom that sends messages via AJAX. Whenever I hit `enter`, with the `data:` parameter, it returns an error, but if I remove `data:`, it doesn't do anything. This is very puzzling, and I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I have:

```
$("#form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "send-message.php",
       data: "message="+$("#message").val()+"&user="+$("#user").val()+"&room="+$("#room").val(),
       success: $("#message").val(""),
       error: $("#message").val("FAIL"),
      });
        return false;
    }
});
```

I use PHP in my AJAX call, so I don't know if that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
...
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "send-message.php",
   data: {message: $("#message").val(), user: $("#user").val(), room: $("#room").val()},
   success: function() { $("#message").val(""); },
   error: function() { $("#message").val("FAIL"); }
});
...
```

**In the above code:**

a) data sent as JSON - this will make sure that any url encoding and escaping will be correctly performed by jQuery as needed

b) success and error options must be callback functions

Answer (score 0):

I would do this just to check if it grabs all the data correct:

```
    var data = {
        message: $('#message').val(),
        user: $('#user').val
    };

    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change these lines:

```
   success: $("#message").val(""),
   error: $("#message").val("FAIL"),
```

to

```
   success: function () { $("#message").val("") },
   error: function () { $("#message").val("FAIL")  // removed trailing comma
```

I wrapped your handlers in a function and removed the trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass your data in POST you should use the javascript key:value format (or JSON format).

Input the following in

```
data: {"message": $("#message").val(),"var2":variable}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object into data, and jQuery takes care of transforming it into the correct form for the type of request you issue, in this case a POST:

```
$("#form").bind("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "send-message.php",
       data: {
         message: $("#message").val(),
         user: $("#user").val(),
         room: $("#room").val()
       },
       success: function () {
         $("#message").val("");
       },
       error: function () {
         $("#message").val("FAIL");
       },
      });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, `error` and `success` are callbacks, so you need to provide a function, not a string if you want it called. Fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

and a hint

```
...
data: $("#form").serialize();
...
```